# How to return an entity except chosen columns using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

It is easy to get only some fields with using hibernate criteria:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user

Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
      .add(Projections.property("Name"), "Name"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
  List<User> list = cr.list();
```

Is it possible to get all fields except "id" and "Name" fields (class User have 20+ fields and I don't want to add all of them into projectionList)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Call:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
List<User> list = cr.list();
```

Comment: This will load fields "id" and "Name" too.

Comment: use can use the example queries to exclude particular columns. Here is the reference : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples